# How to make Illustrator bezier handles easier to click?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, anchor-point, bezier-curve

My current work monitor has 4K resolution. It's great for design, however it has been hard do click on Illustrator bezier handle point anchors.

Is it possible to make those points bigger and the lines more visible (it has only 1px thickness)?

[image]

Comment: Hi Daniel, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: I have the same Problem on a 4K Display with Windows 10. Even if I change the Anchor point size on the preferences above, there is no big change. The points are still very tiny, and just nearly impossible to take it at first time.
Hope an update will change this bug. :/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Under Preferences > Selection & Anchor Display, you can change the size of anchor points and direction handles. Choose the option all the way on the right. [image: Illustrator > Preferences > Selection and Anchor Display]

Comment: Over a decade of frustration... finally solved! 